# suspicious data structure change in r when making a list of two arima models

Tags: r, list, data-structures, data.table

example data here:

```
err <- ts(c(0.6100, 1.3500, 1.0300, 0.9600, 1.1100, 0.8350 , 0.8800 , 1.0600 , 1.3800 , 1.6200,  1.5800 , 1.2800 , 1.3000 , 1.4300 , 2.1500 , 1.9100 , 1.8300 , 1.9500  ,1.9999, 1.8500 , 1.5500 , 1.9800  ,1.7044  ,1.8593 , 1.9900 , 2.0400, 1.8950,  2.0100 , 1.6900 , 2.1800 ,2.2150,  2.1293 , 2.1000 , 2.1200 , 2.0500 , 1.9000,  1.8350, 1.9000 ,1.9500 , 1.7800 , 1.5950,  1.8500 , 1.8400,  1.5800, 1.6100 , 1.7200 , 1.8500 , 1.6700,  1.8050,  1.9400,  1.5000 , 1.3100 , 1.4864,  1.2400 , 0.9300 , 1.1400, -0.6100, -0.4300 ,-0.4700 ,-0.3450), frequency = 7, start = c(23, 1), end = c(31, 4))
```

I'll just create two `arima` models and make a list 
 and a data.table of two models:

```
m1 <- arima(x = err, order=c(0,0,5), include.mean=F)
m2 <- arima(x = err, order=c(0,1,1), include.mean=F)
m.list <- list(m1, m2)
m.comb <- c(m1, m2)
m.dt <- data.table(a=m1, b=m2)
```

now `m.list[1]` or `m.list$coef` gave the coefs of the first model; and this does not make sense to me, I would expect `m.list[1]` to give me the complete first model and `m.list$coef` shouldn't even exist. Of course I am assuming R is at least behaving a tiny little bit like other languages such as python, or C++, let alone others. I can be very wrong.

`m.dt` seems to completely lose the structure and becomes a bit weird:

```
m.a <- m.dt[, "a"]
m.a
# output
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 a
 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1.105733,1.221225,1.215059,0.939646,0.570557
 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.18465
 3:  0.019905835, 0.012235097,-0.002690923,-0.018219027,-0.018363215, 0.012235097, 0.020627900, 0.007399694,-0.003498485, 0.001069299,-0.002690923, 0.007399694, 0.027766607, 0.042303357, 0.033649641,-0.018219027,-0.003498485, 0.042303357, 0.097345388, 0.071969149,-0.018363215, 0.001069299, 0.033649641, 0.071969149, 0.068308454,...
 4:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE
 5:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -36.47995
 6:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 82.95989
 7:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0,5,0,0,7,0,...
 8:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.241144876, 0.672481832,-0.319954235, 0.066421765, 0.378785306, 0.003550614,...
 9:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <call>
10:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        x
11:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0
12:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0
13:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       60

14:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   <list>
```

above is literally just a summary and if we intend to access `m.dt[, "a"][14]`, it literally just prints "list" and nothing else.

How do I make a list of two models that retain its original structure? (it seems to be a very basic implementation for data consistency in any programming language)

**EDIT**

where I meant to say `m.comb[1]` and `m.comb$coef` yield only coefficients, I marked `m.list`, that was an error and pointed out by @42- in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a column directly, wrap it in a `list` environment to maintain the structure of the `models`

```
m.dt <- data.table(a=list(m1), b=list(m2))
m.dt
#        a       b
#1: <Arima> <Arima>
```

It can be also be created from 'm.list'

```
m.dt <- as.data.table(lapply(setNames(m.list, c('a', 'b')), list))
```

Now, we extract the models as

```
m.dt$a[[1]]
```

extract the coefficients

```
coef(m.dt$a[[1]])
```

Comment: thanks very much for a swift answer, it works. I have a follow-up if you don't mind: why does R have such cumbersome behaviour?

Comment: @stucash  The model structures are a bit complicated.  If you check the `str(m1)` or `str(m2)`, will understand the structures stacked inside it.  When you convert to a data.frame/data.table etc. it expects the columns to be a vector (can have some attributes, but if the attributes are way too much, it would coerce to make it formatted for storage.  I would store it in a `list` as a wrapper to not get affected

Comment: ok.. now I at least can make some sense, I'll play with the data structures like you suggest, hope I can get a better understanding. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You said that m.list[1] was giving you just coefficients. That's not really a correct understanding. The R interpreter's REPL is displaying the result of `print.arima` done on the first model.

```
> m.list[1]
    [[1]]

    Call:
    arima(x = err, order = c(0, 0, 5), include.mean = F)

    Coefficients:
             ma1     ma2     ma3     ma4     ma5
          1.1057  1.2212  1.2151  0.9396  0.5706
    s.e.  0.1411  0.1436  0.1666  0.3120  0.2614

    sigma^2 estimated as 0.1846:  log likelihood = -36.48,  aic = 84.96
```

If you had assigned the result of `m.list[1]` to another name you would have found that it was a list whose first element was identical to `m1`.

```
> m3 <- m.list[1]
> identical( m3[[1]], m1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out. I was lost in my numerous trial and error and apparently got confused. I was actually referred to `m.comb <- c(m1, m2)` and if we do `m.comb[1]` or or `m.comb$coef` they would  yield the same results, which are just the coefs. I'll leave my mistake in the original post. I'll however add `m.comb` in for completeness.